# Google maps is not 100% Loaded when you start Android . (not always)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with a map that contains a geo-location, directions and markers. The map is the start screen which is directly shown after the app launches. I want the map to show geolocation (position) and markers, but i have to reload it (ripple emulator), to see what i want. After the app launches, the map is clear and no geolocation or markers are shown.

I think the script may not load to 100%, sometimes it works without giving me this problem.

I use cordova, initialize the map in this classic way bottom script:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and to call :

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

API and script and I put the code on the top of the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "charge"?

Comment: Load* .... Google translate <.<

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it does not work at all, in the device map does not load the function or disappear when you "zoom " and runs very slowly